# Read dead tuples data

Tags: greenplum

Is it possible to read the dead tuples from a table using xmin or xmax column or by changing any catalog parameters? Is there any way to read the old data which was updated?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden debugging variable -- 
I'm not going to post it here, because I believe that it's dangerous.

Google: greenplum+show+deleted

It's only good until VACUUM, after which those tuples are deleted.

This debugging GUC is for viewing only -- if  you mess with the xmin, xmax, ctid, ... trying to undelete something, you are certainly going to cause corruption.

You can, however, export those rows without the hidden columns, then re-import.

Comment: After VACUUM, if the space in between records is used by new inserted records, for selects from that table, will it take more time than normal to read as the data is not in ordered format ?

Comment: Internal indexing and fast table scans generally make this a non-issue.

There are certainly incremental performance gains for contiguous data reads if you are ingesting lots of data -- but if you are filtering and selecting -- not so much.

Pivotal support recommends REORGANIZE over VACUUM FULL, which is a very expensive operation.

Comment: Could you please let me know if there is there any link to know how the costs are calculated in explain plan for legacy optimizer and PQO optimizer?

Comment: That's an extensive subject -- indexes, table scans, joins... and not something that could be answered here. 

For example, take a look at this index cost estimation document --
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/index-cost-estimation.html
And that's just the index cost ... you could google this stuff all day.

Comment: Is there any query to find table bloat? gp_toolkit.gp_bloat_diag is not giving correct results

Comment: gp_toolkit relies on pg_stat -- so you need to make sure ANALYZE is run in order to have correct details. It will look at the size of the table on disk, and the size of the table from stats to give you your result.

You can also search the pivotal KB for articles on validation with scripts.